# How can I convert wav to a float array buffer?

Tags: dtmf, wav

I need to be able to read a wav file and load the data into my buffer.  I can use that array to convolve with other float array. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [**sox**](http://sox.sourceforge.net/).  You can use sox to read-in a `wav` file, and output the samples as floating-point values between `-1` and `1`.